# Can someone help me with a C programming task?

Tags: c

I need to write a program which would take a number of any length, would put its digits in opposite order (for example from 12365 would make 56321) and check if those two numbers can be divided from all its digits. If both numbers can be divided from every digit then program should output both numbers: the given one and the opposite one. For now My program can only reverse that number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int i, m, n, atb = 0, nr = 1, skait = 0, j;
    printf("Iveskite intervalo pradzia ir pabaiga:\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    //---
    for(i = m; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int temp = i;
        int dalys[skait];
        do
        {

            atb = atb*10 + temp%10;
            dalys[skait] = temp;
            temp = temp / 10;
            skait++;

        }
        while (temp != 0);
//-------------------------------------------
        for(j = 1; j <= skait; j++){
            int dal = pow(10,(skait-1));

        }



//-------------------------------------------
        printf("\n%d skaicius: %d", nr, atb);
        printf("\nSkaicius susideda is %d skaitmenu.", skait);
        atb=0;
        skait=0;
        nr++;

    }




    return 0;
}
```

I already started to try to solve the division part... but I cant find how to make the program take every digit and make it check that division part...

Comment: If needed I can change those output messages into English.

Comment: You can store all that digits in an array, then one-by-one check the division with all elements with the array.

Comment: What is the technical question that you want us to answer? Please look into the help section how to ask questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written also this version! I think is better of the previous! This solution uses a vector smaller than the version in the other reply and it doesn't make useless divisions! :) Furthermore the function compute() returns 1 if the condition requested are verified (0 elsewhere), then you may easily move the final printf out of the function in the main!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SEESTEPS
#ifdef SEESTEPS
#define Dprintf(a...) printf(a);
#else
#define Dprintf(a...) ;
#endif

int compute(uint64_t x,int zeroGo)
{
    uint64_t y,z,t;
    int div[10];
    int cntdiv,i;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        div[i]=0;

    z=x;y=0;cntdiv=0;
    while(z) {
        t=(z%10);
        if (!div[t]) {
            cntdiv++;
            div[t]=1;
        }
        y*=10;y+=t;
        z/=10;
    }

    Dprintf("%lu => Inverted %lu\n",x,y);

    if (zeroGo || !div[0]) {
        t=div[0];
        for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
            if (!div[i])
                continue;
            Dprintf("%lu mod %d = %lu\n",x,i,x%i );
            if ( (x%i) )
                break;
            Dprintf("%lu mod %d = %lu\n",y,i,y%i );
            if ( (y%i) )
                break;
            t++;
        }
    } else {
        t=cntdiv-1;
    }

    //Dprintf("%d %d -",cntdiv,t);
    if ((int)t==cntdiv) {
        printf("%lu %lu\n",x,y);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    uint64_t f,t;
    int cnt=0;

    printf("From...: ");
    scanf("%lu",&f);
    printf("To.....: ");
    scanf("%lu",&t);

    for(;f<=t;f++)
        cnt+=compute(f,1);

    printf("%d\n",cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Mantas Daškevičius. See also the new version above this comment!

Answer (score 0):

Try this! It should be run as you require! If you comment the code #define SEESTEPS the code prints only the required result! This code computes only one number at time, you may transform it in a function!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SEESTEPS
#ifdef SEESTEPS
#define Dprintf(a...) printf(a);
#else
#define Dprintf(a...) ;
#endif

int main(void) {
    uint64_t x,y,z;
    uint64_t div[20];
    int cntdiv,i;

    scanf("%lu",&x);

    /* This inverts the number and computes the digit */
    z=x;y=0;cntdiv=0;
    while(z) {
        div[cntdiv]=(z%10);
        y*=10;y+=div[cntdiv];
        z/=10;cntdiv++;
    }

    Dprintf("Inverted %lu\n",y);
    /* This verifies the divisibility! */
    for(i=0;i<cntdiv;i++) {
        if (!div[i])
            continue; /* Or break; if you prefer */
        Dprintf("%lu mod %lu = %lu\n",x,div[i],x%div[i] );
        if ( (x%div[i]))
            break;
        Dprintf("%lu mod %lu = %lu\n",y,div[i],y%div[i] );
        if ( (y%div[i]))
           break;
    }

    if (i==cntdiv)
        printf("%lu %lu",x,y);

    return 0;
}
```